# Can you rotate an element using a input value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to use the `Input[type=range]` to rotate the red circle with the id of outer, I tried to select the circle's style, then transform, and that is equal to the value of the input, but it has to be between the parenthesis in `rotateZ()`, which is a string. Here is my code;

```js
var value = document.getElementById("slider").value;
        console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("inner").style.transform = document.getElementById("slider").value;
```

```css
 body {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    #outer {
        background:red;
        height:20vw;
        position:relative;
        border-radius:50%;
        width:20vw;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    #inner {
        transform:translateY(10%);
        border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        background:darkgreen;
        width:10%;
        height:50%;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
    <input min="0" max="360" type="range" id="slider">
```

But it doesn't work. I need to somehow put the value between parenthesis.

**EDIT, SOLUTION;**

I used Temperate Literals and put the variable between   and {} like this `{variable}` inside of the rotate's parentheses.

Comment: `const value = document.getElementById("slider").value; document.getElementById("inner").style.transform = \`rotate(${transform}deg)\`;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, first of all as you said you can't just set it to a number, but need to set it to a string, here using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Secondly, since you want the rotation linked to the slider, you'll need to add a listener to the slider in this case listening for an [`input event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) which gives the most immediate feedback.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = `rotate(${slider.value}deg)`;
});
```

```css
body {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    #outer {
        background:red;
        height:20vw;
        position:relative;
        border-radius:50%;
        width:20vw;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    #inner {
        transform:translateY(10%);
        border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        background:darkgreen;
        width:10%;
        height:50%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<input min="0" max="360" type="range" id="slider">
```

Comment: Thanks! But does the rotate have to be in `` quotes? Or can it be normal ' or "?

Comment: if using a template literal you have to use backticks \` \`. Alternatively you can concat using single or double quotes `"rotate(" + slider.value + "deg)";`

Comment: @Proking73Questioneer follow the link provided, and you'll understand the purpose . reminder : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a string that conforms to the CSS property, such as `rotateZ(180deg)`. Mind the `deg` unit, because it will not work without one.

If you want to translate the hand at the same time, you need to put that into the string as well since there is only one transform property and you will overwrite it. The order is important here: first rotate, then translate, or the result will change. Not to forget, you need to move the `transform-origin` as well (see example).

Add a listener to the slider's input event, otherwise the value will only be applied once when the script loads. Best use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with backticks (`` `rotateZ(${value}) translate(10%)` ``) since it is more convenient, but you can also add the strings together (`'rotateZ(' + value + 'deg) translate(10%)'`).

**Edit:** Or you can just rotate the outer circle like in the other answer, saves you accounting for the `translate`. However, if you also want to add something like numbers of a clock to the circle, they would be rotated as well in that case.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
    hand = document.getElementById("inner");

slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  hand.style.transform = `rotateZ(${this.value}deg) translateY(10%)`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

#outer {
  background:red;
  height:20vw;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:20vw;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

#inner {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(10%);
  transform-origin: top center;
  border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:darkgreen;
  width:10%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
<input min="0" max="360" type="range" id="slider">
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const inputValue = document.querySelector('#slider')
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner')
const rotate = document.querySelector('.rotate')
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
let oldVariable = 0
// Listen to any change in the progress bar
inputValue.addEventListener("change", function(){
  const newVariable = inputValue.value
  root.style.setProperty('--my-start-deg',`${oldVariable}deg`);
   root.style.setProperty('--my-end-deg', `${newVariable}deg`);
  inner.classList.remove("rotate");
  // Reset CSS Keyframes
  void inner.offsetWidth;
  
  inner.classList.add("rotate");
  oldVariable = inputValue.value;
});
```

```css
:root {
    --my-start-deg: 0deg;
    --my-end-deg: 0deg;
}

#frame{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border:10px solid #000;
  border-radius:100%;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
   transiton:all 3s;
}

.inner{
 position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
  height:100px;
  width:2px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.rotate {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation: progressBar 3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  transiton:all 3s;
  
}


@keyframes progressBar {
    0% {  transform: rotate(var(--my-start-deg)); }
    100% {  transform: rotate(var(--my-end-deg)); }
}
```

```html
<input min="0" max="360" value="0" type="range" id="slider">
<div id="frame">
  <div class="inner rotate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).